# When I run this cypher cql 'return all( x in [] where any(y in x where x='a'))'

Tags: neo4j, cypher, graph-databases, spring-data-neo4j

When I run this cypher cql `return all( x in [] where any(y in x where x='a'))`,it will gets the result 'true'.When I run cql`return  'a' in []`,it gets the result 'false', But why the first cql will gets true?

Comment: Presumably because in the first statement, there are no `x`es that satisfy the criteria, so it's true that all `x` are in `[]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you try this query : `RETURN any(x in null WHERE x='a')`
Result is `null` because it's neither `true` neither `false` due to the list that is `null`.

Now if you try this query : `RETURN all(x IN [] WHERE null)`
Result is `true`, because the list is empty, so you can put whatever where clauses you want (even if `WHERE null` does not mean anything).

So the conjunction of those queries, ie. `return all( x in [] where any(y in x where x='a'))` is `true`